# Set Limit on String

Tags: php, html

I was making a textbox for search and I want to set limit to the textbox. For example if I searched "derf" then I just input "de" instead of "derf" I will not get any result or it will echo "minimum of 4 letters. . (blaahh blahh)" Thanks guys.. PHP

Comment: I would use js for this

Comment: [What have you tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)? Welcome to StackOverflow, please read the [FAQs](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on asking questions.

Comment: Sir Christopher Morrissey thank you for the reply sir. Can you state what js should I use?

Comment: Questions asking for code must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the *expected* results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer using one of two methods... One, the HTML pattern attribute:

```
<input name="InputName" pattern=".{3}">
```

Or if you wish to do this Server sided:

```
if (strlen($_POST['InputName']) < 3){
  echo "A Meaningful error message"; 
  exit;
}
```

Comment: Would the downvoter care to share his/her issue?

Comment: Thank you sir Daryl Gill, you saved my day

Comment: I upvoted you to match the downvote... 
Can't even think why someone would downvote you there...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pattern` to force you to enter at least 4 chars:

```
<input name="blah" pattern=".{4,}">
```

[Demo right here.](http://jsfiddle.net/hnScJ/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in multiple ways.

1. Write your own java script function.
2. If you are using jQuery use 'validator' plugin to set minimum size on textbox.